# Origin of the velar "rr" sound in Puerto Rico

Tags: pronunciación, puerto-rico

I have always wondered the existence, alone in Puerto Rico of all Spanish language countries, of the VELAR "rr" sound, similar to a common pronunciation seen in French (as in the word "Paris"). Sometimes it sounds like a deep guttural and sometimes it sounds as a throat-clearing. But it does not reproduce itself in any other country...

Comment: Actually, it's *not* the same sound as in French.   Puerto Rican <rr> is [x]~[h].  French <r>, depending on region can be anything from [ʁ], [ʀ], [r], [χ], or [ɣ].

Comment: Se ha hablado en una respuesta a esta pregunta sobre un posible origen indígena, pero los vocablos amerindios ("taínos") que han llegado a nosotros no parecen incorporar ese sonido.

Answer (score 3):

Según [El Español en Puerto Rico](https://books.google.cl/books?id=2JonBgbu528C&printsec=frontcover&hl=es#v=onepage&q&f=false) de Tomás Navarro Tomás (1948), existen varias hipótesis:

- Influencia del francés a través de Haití. Pero es poco probable porque en República Dominicana, que tiene mayor contacto con Haití, no se da este fenómeno.
- Influencia de lenguas africanas, considerando que en Río de Janeiro se da una rr similar y que hay abundancia de población negra tanto en Puerto Rico como en Brasil. Pero es poco probable porque la rr velar no se manifiesta especialmente ni de manera más clara en el elemento negro de la población.
- Acomodación del sonido castellano al medio indígena, bajo alguna influencia especial de la fonética boricua. Ésta hipótesis es la que le parece más plausible al autor, dado que la rr velar parece estar más arraigada en antiguos reductos de tradición local, especialmente jíbara.